# Summarize polynomial fit to data in a single number, without plotting

Tags: python, scipy, polynomial-math

I'm trying to find exponential growth trends in a polynomial model and having issues identifying them. I've looked at scipy.optimize.curve_fit in python and can't seem to figure out how to know the shape of the curve without plotting it. The end goal is to find trends that look like:

[image: polynomial]

I tried:

```
z = np.polyfit(x, y, 3)
f = np.poly1d(z)

# calculate new x's and y's
x_new = np.linspace(x[0], x[-1], 50)
y_new = f(x_new)

plt.plot(x,y,'o', x_new, y_new)
plt.xlim([x[0]-1, x[-1] + 1 ])
plt.show()
```

But I cannot identify the shape of the curve in a single value, which could then be sorted to see which have positive trends.

Comment: I don't see any exponential growth going on. I see a 'high frequency' signal on a 'low frequency' background. I would not attempt to fit with a polynomial at all.

Comment: why not simply look at average growth rates? either of the trend or the raw data, or even just between the first and last point. if the first point is well below the last point, you'll have growth in the interim.

Comment: @user2241910 Good question. How would you detect continuous growth, not just a spike in the middle of the trendline?

Comment: @JonCuster How would you match other trend lines to the one in the question?

Comment: Well, the ripple looks like one narrow frequency range. How about an fft to get the fast responses, then either another sine or a low order polynomial. But, really, if this is data you use a physics-informed model of the situation.

Comment: If this really is expontial growth, you can take the log of your data to get a linear series which you can compare with other series by its slope (a single number). You can still use polyfit to find the slope by fitting a degree 1 polynomial. The slope will equal the expontial growth rate, so no interpretation is lost.

Answer (score 0):

> identify the shape of the curve in a single value

This can be done with `polyfit` by extracting just one, most important, coefficient of the fitted polynomial. Of course, a single value can only give a rough idea of some trend: up/down, concave up/concave down. Here is how:

```
x = np.arange(600)
y = np.exp(x/300) + np.cos(x/30) + np.random.uniform(size=x.shape)  # simulated data

slope = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)[0]
concavity = np.polyfit(x, y, 2)[0]
print(slope, concavity)
```

The slope is the leading coefficient of the linear fit, which  is positive (about 0.01), indicating upward trend.

The concavity, the leading coefficient of the quadratic fit, is also positive (the shape is concave up on average).

[image: data]